# Also use comma as a word separator in diff

Tags: git, diff

How can I add `,` as a word separator for git diff --word-diff?

For instance I would like the diff to recognize that

```
function(A,B,C) -> function(A, B, C)
```

only has added the spaces instead of replacing the whole line.

Comment: The answers address commas **and** spaces. For commas **only**, we use `--word-diff-regex='[^,]+'`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `--word-diff-regex`:

```
   --word-diff-regex=<regex>
       Use <regex> to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs
       of non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies --word-diff unless it
       was already enabled.

       Every non-overlapping match of the <regex> is considered a word.
       Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and
       ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences. You may want to
       append |[^[:space:]] to your regular expression to make sure that
       it matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that contains a
       newline is silently truncated(!) at the newline.

       The regex can also be set via a diff driver or configuration
       option, see gitattributes(1) or git-config(1). Giving it explicitly
       overrides any diff driver or configuration setting. Diff drivers
       override configuration settings.
```

I never used it but i guess that `git diff --word-diff-regex="[^[:space:],]+"` may work.

Comment: Any idea how to set it in git config, to use this regex by default, when I specify --word-diff rather than me having to specify the regex each time.

Comment: Answered my own question: `git config --global diff.wordRegex [^[:space:],]+`

Comment: Only flaw in this is it won't show commas that were added/removed. To see those too, use `--word-diff-regex="[^[:space:],]+|[,]+"`

Comment: @user6506750 It does show the comma for me.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to KurzedMetal's answer: without the quotes it works even better since it doesn't break my bashs autocompletion when hitting TAB.

`git diff --word-diff-regex=[^[:space:],]+`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `-w`/`--ignore-all-space`, although that may ignore more whitespace than you like.

Comment: -b ignores a bit less whitespace