# Improve visualization of CSV diffs in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, git-diff

Locally on my computer, I could improve the *git diff* for CSVs via the tool daff (http://paulfitz.github.io/daff/). Now my local *git diffs* are based on cells and not lines for modified CSV files.

Is there a possible way to achieve this also in Gitlab for Commits and MergeRequests?

The only documentation I found about this is an entry about *Diff Viewers* in some developer notes, but it was not of much help: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/diffs.html#viewers

In case that the format of CSV files is of any importance - here a small example:

```
'column 1','column 2','column 3' 
'value','value','value'
'value','value','value'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483000/2641825 and [Tool to diff CSV files at the field level and output results to CSV maintaining the colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211357/tool-to-diff-csv-files-at-the-field-level-and-output-results-to-csv-maintaining)

To consider commas a separator when using word diff on csv files, you can use

```
git diff --word-diff-regex="[^[:space:],]+"
# Or
git diff --color-words="[^[:space:],]+" x.csv y.csv
```